# Jupyter notebook and spawning asyncio tasks from a library

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio

I'm writing a library for use with Jupyter notebook. One of the things it does is asynchronously update progress in the notebook cell output. In the library I have a function:

```py
def request_result():
    start_result_calculation()  # starts a calculation and returns immediately
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(report_progress())
    result = wait_for_result()  # waits for the calc to complete and returns the result
    return result
```

If I now call `result = request_result()` in a Jupyter notebook cell, the `report_progress()` coroutine is never invoked. On the other hand, If I return the `Task` back to the cell:

```py
def calculate_result():
    start_result_calculation()
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(report_progress())
```

then when `calculate_result()` is executed in a notebook cell the `report_progress()` is invoked. Why is that, and is there a way to have the first function work as expected, spawning a background task and returning the final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work-around that works in my case is to run the task from a separate thread:

```py
class _ProgressThread(threading.Thread):
   def run(self):
      asyncio.run(report_progress())


def request_result():
    start_result_calculation()
    _ProgressThread().start()
    result = wait_for_result()
    return result
```

I still need to use `asyncio` in that thread, due to the requirements of the code that runs inside `report_progress()`.